# why "&" is used in place of comma?

Tags: java, operators

**This line is from "The Java Programming Language" by Arnold, Gosling, and Holmes:**

```
interface SortedCharSeqCollection<E extends Comparable<E> & CharSequence> { ... }
```

The **"&"** means **"and also"**, so in this example the collection could hold Strings, which implements both interfaces.
**I am not sure why a comma wasn't used and would love to understand it from you guys.**

Comment: The actual reason is much more concrete: see `Map<K, V>`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik didn't get that ?

Comment: Comma is already occupied as a separator in a *list of type parameters*. `SortedCharSeqCollection<E extends Comparable<E>, CharSequence>` is not a syntax error: it has a defined, but completely different, meaning.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik makes some sense, but m still not sure .

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik this makes perfect sense now. Petty this question has been closed, you deserve a good number of upvotes for this!

Comment: @Eugene that is pretty ok , the main objective was to get the answer, up-down votes doesn't matter .

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because **&** has much more *logical sense* then using comma.

This sign is already the LOGICAL *and operation* in binary, so it makes a lot of sense to use it here also.